# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n(n!)}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to study the infinite series with general term $a_n=\frac{3^n(n!)}{n^n}$. I can see that $a_n$ goes to $\infty$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$ but I can't prove it. Could someone help me find:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n(n!)}{n^n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Apply [d'Alembert Ratio Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertRatioTest.html)

to check $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac3{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}=\frac3e>1$$

Comment: Thank you @lab bhattacharjee. I'm aware of that, but is it possible to compute the limit of $a_n$ directly?

Comment: @palio, but you know $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ is inconclusive( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test)

Comment: Actually $\lim{a_n}=\infty$ not $0$.

Comment: @palio, how do you know?

Comment: I checked it on wolframalpha and on Maple

Answer (score 1):

lab bhattacharjee's answer shows that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = + \infty$ since $a_n \ge a_0 \left(\frac{3}{e}\right)^n \ge 1.1^n$: you start with a positive value and keep multiplying it by a number greater than $1.1$.

If you want an approximation to $a_n$ then you can use [Stirling's approximation to the factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to give something like $$a_n \approx \left(\frac{3}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(1+\frac{1}{12n}\right)$$ in the sense that it gives 99.89% of the actual value of $a_n$ for $n=1$ and then improves, giving 99.99997% of the actual value for $n = 100$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Root Test, what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1\over n}$?

Comment: yes i know but i wanted to show directly that $a_n$ does not tend to zero. Is this possible?

Comment: Both answers so far already showed you one way: if you look at the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{3^nn!}$$ then both answers show you that the series **converge**, which means the inverse of your sequence converges to zero and thus your sequence converges to infinity (since it is a positive one)...